# assembly replacement and class inheritance

Tags: c#, wcf, dll

A WCF service named `Portal.WebServices.TaskListService` uses a codebehind file `TaskListService.svc.cs`. In this file declare a type named `TaskListService` that inherits from the type `TaskListServiceBase`. and implements an interface named `ITaskListService`. So:

```
TaskListService: TaskListServiceBase, ITaskListService

   ^                     ^                  ^   
   |                     |                  |
 application               separate assembly
```

I want to deploy the `TaskListService` **once** on the webserver and put `TaskListServiceBase` and the interface into a **separate assembly** that is referenced by the application that hosts `TaskListService`. So when I want to add, remove or update functionality in the web service I only have to copy the new assembly into the application's bin folder.

*Since this happens during runtime I wonder if there are **any penalties or caveats** for this practice (besides of the use of compile time constants etc), or **if this scenario is even possible**, or if there are better practices for doing this.*

So basically, my question is: **I want to update functionality to a WCF service without redeploying the whole application, only the assembly that is updated**

<sup>(yes I feel a bit stupid here)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation of interface and base class in another assembly is possible and correct (Separated Interface is a pattern describing this for just interfaces, and the same pattern applies for base classes).

Regarding the deployment, you can do that as the assemblies are shadow-copied by IIS. However, once the new assembly is copied, I assume you have to recycle the application so the new assembly is loaded.

I did this manually for a Windows Service, that launched a separated AppDomain with shadow copy enabled, so I could remotely update an assembly and force a restart of the service.

Answer (score 1):

This is a practice I follow, there are no downsides that I know of, only benefits. I take it one step further, in that I do not use the code behind. So in your example above, TaskListService.cs would live in a `ServiceImplementations` assembly, separate from the `ServiceContracts` assembly.

This allows you to break down your contracts/implementations into multiple assemblies if needed (perhaps separated by domain) and update them independently.